# problems when I consume an api in ionic 5, NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, api, rest, ionic-framework, get

At first I had cors problems and I managed to solve it, but now I get the following error.
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIEkL.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Rfp.png)

this is my service

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {

constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

 obtenerDatos(): Observable<any>{
 return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/');}

}
```

this is my principal.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthServiceService } from '../providers/auth-service.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
selector: 'app-principal',
templateUrl: './principal.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./principal.page.scss'],
})

export class PrincipalPage implements OnInit {

profesional: any;

constructor( public proveedor: AuthServiceService)
{
  this.proveedor.obtenerDatos( )
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {this.profesional = data; },
    (error) => {console.log(error); }
  );
  }
ngOnInit() {
}
inViewDidLoad(){ }
}
```

and my html

```
<div class="ion-page" id="main-content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>Bienvenido</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>      
  <ion-content class="ion-padding">
      <h2>API</h2>
      <ion-list>
        <button ion-item *ngFor="let profe of profesional">
          {{profe.rut_profesional }} 
        </button>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
  </div>
```

I've searched and searched and I can't find the error, pls help me :(

[console log this profesional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXE3a.png)

[what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0n6B.png)

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMqRw.png)

[and my interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezLko.png)

Comment: First you need to do this. console.log(this.profesional) Then check the structure of data. If you can add that screenshot also here.

Comment: @JanithaRasanga leave the screenshot at the end of the publication

Comment: Now you want, get the name of mataData?

Comment: This is nested object, and objects can't be extracted with *ngFor, in this case wither if u have access to api, u can send the data as array and not object or when data is recieved u can extract the data through coding and save the extracted data in a variable and this variable should be set in the ngfor so ur work could be successful as u need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let profe of profesional.msg.metaData">
  {{profe.name}} 
</button>
```

Answer have in your question. ngFor support to array. In your case you try to iterate an object. Before the iterate you need to get out array part from object. Then you can iterate it.

Comment: I already implemented it but it only gives me the problem that it is not defined, the problem is where?

Answer (score 0):

I addition to [Rashanja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9423643/janitha-rasanga)'s answer you can try declaring interfaces for msg and metadata (if it's an Object) in your module.

Comment: I created the interface.ts file, but now I get this

Comment: The screenshots are at the end of the publication, the last 2

Comment: As the error says the code is crashing in line 24 of principal.page.ts. I have no idea what's there. 
What's the structure of data you expect to get from the GET request?